# Como posso criar um método que pesquisa no banco de dados e retorna um valor em TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript

Tenho um projeto que guardava as informações em um JSON e vi a necessidade de migrar para um banco de dados. Ao chamar a query ele responde com o array que preciso retornar, como posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

A tua pergunta é um bocado confusa. O teu objectivo é encontrar apenas um elemento da base de dados?

Se for isso, como já tens o array da query, podes simplesmente fazer um find nesse array de acordo com a condição que desejas.

Exemplo com o id:

```
coursesArray.find(elem => elem.id === id))
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).